# Using c# interface in a c++ project with VS express 1013

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, clr

I am trying to include a c# interface into a c++ header file which belongs to a clr library.
I add the additional directory and as soon as I include the interface and try to build the c++ project, I get loads of errors leading to the cs file, like:

[image]

Do I mess up some VS settings?

Comment: Your problem is you seem to have put c++ code into a c# file. At a guess (but youve shown no code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to #include "IImagesToVideoConverter.cs". The C++ compiler cannot understand c# code. You need to put a c# project and a c++ project in the same solution, reference the c# project from the c++ project, and (i think) `#using <the.dll>`

Answer (score 0):

including a C# source in a C++ compile makes no sense. They are different languages, why would you ever expect this to work?

Perhaps you want to make a COM interface between them, in which case you use a [`#import`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) directive.